# Why does this bitwise operator return a negative number?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I was just reading a tutorial for bitwise operators and I don't understand why this number is -61.

```
unsigned int a = 60;    /* 60 = 0011 1100 */  
unsigned int b = 13;    /* 13 = 0000 1101 */
int c = 0; 
c = ~a;          /*-61 = 1100 0011 */
printf("Line 4 - Value of c is %d\n", c );
```

shouldn't 11000011 be 195? (128+64+2+1)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm

Comment: You're storing it into a signed integer

Comment: What gave you the idea these integers were 8-bit, anyway? EDIT: I see the link you gave uses 8-bit math. That happens to give the right answer for signed ints due to the way two's complement works, but for unsigned ints, you'd get a much bigger number than 195.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it shouldn't be!

you probabely want to use `unsigned char` for all your parameters

```
unsigned char a = 60;
unsigned char b = ~a;
char c = ~a;
printf("b=%d\nc=%d\n", b, c);
```

gives the output :

```
b=195
c=-61
```

Comment: `char c = ~a;` is an out-of-range assignment which causes implementation-defined behaviour (on common systems that selects the lowest 8 bits and reinterprets as `char` although that isn't guaranteed in general).